# Convert login to OpenID account

Tags: support, user-accounts, openid

I already had an account on Stack Exchange and receive some newsletters.  I never had an OpenID account but it is very hard to get logged in the "old" way.  How can I convert my login to OpenID?

Comment: [Add a login](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login-add)?

Comment: What do you mean by "the 'old' way"? I see one credential on your account, and it's an email/password combo that (technically) logs you in with a Stack Exchange OpenID. Are you talking about a different account that you're trying to get access to?

Comment: When I log in, I see the invitation to use my OpenID account but I don't have one.  The dialog for logging in with my email address and password are hard to find.  I'm not interested in OpenID.  Eventually I am able to log in but it takes some digging to find the dialog for email/passwd.  Maybe it's just me.  If you really think I need an OpenID to log into StackExchange then I need to create one but I can't see how to do it without creating a new account on StackExchange.
  Sorry for the confusion.
  Ken